# Including untouched LGPL library in a MIT-licenced project

Tags: licensing, license-compatibility, mit, law, lgpl

Can I include a library licenced under LGPL 2.1 in an MIT-licenced project without any legal problems?

Since it's not a compiled language, I would provide the full untouched source code of the library (including the copyright notice) in a sub-directory of my project. My classes would then use some of the library's classes.

The [text of the licence](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-2.1.en.html) says:

> 1. You may copy and distribute verbatim copies of the Library's complete source code as you receive it, in any medium, provided that you conspicuously and appropriately publish on each copy an appropriate copyright notice and disclaimer of warranty; keep intact all the notices that refer to this License and to the absence of any warranty; and distribute a copy of this License along with the Library.

Does this mean that what I want to do is legal?

Comment: Are you simply asking if you including the source code this way is allowed or are you asking if your use of the library is okay from all aspects?

Comment: I'm asking if my use of the library is okay, considering the way I'm including the source code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can I include a library licenced under LGPL 2.1 in an MIT-licenced project without any legal problems?

Yes. Your only LGPL requirements apply to the LGPL library and not to your MIT-licensed code...

> Since it's not a compiled language, I would provide the full untouched source code of the library (including the copyright notice) in a sub-directory of my project. My classes would then use some of the library's classes.

Assuming you are making no modifications to the LGPL-licensed code, you are doing the right thing.