# Source and jar without dependencies under MIT, runnable jar with dependencies under GPL

Tags: mit, license-compatibility, lgpl, java, maven

I would like to develop **MIT** (or Apache 2.0)**-licensed software** using an **LGPL library**.

*As far as I understand this is allowed as long as I'm distributing the library in a separate jar file and loading it from my MIT-licensed jar.*

Therefore I could have **my project** (source and compiled jar without dependencies) **under MIT or Apache 2.0 license, am I right?**

If I now were to publish the **jar-with-dependencies** (jar that contains all class files for my program and the used libraries; produced by maven) I'd need to do so **under LGPL or GPL** if I understand it correctly. Would this affect the license for my sources and the compiled jar without dependencies?

*I'd like to make the process as easy as possible for people with smaller technical knowledge (therefore the bundled jar) but would also like to use a very permissive license for anyone to use the project.*

Is this possible? What precautions should I take?

**Similar topics:**

*[This topic](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/10400/distributing-lgpl-library-openal-as-part-of-the-mit-licensed-game-engine) is similar but I think it doesn't specify if I could also distribute compiled classes under MIT next to the LGPL licensed classes in the jar with all dependencies.*

*[This topic](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/5175/including-untouched-lgpl-library-in-a-mit-licenced-project) talks specifically about the source but once again not about compiled classes.*